# Android Room Migration NonNull primitive types

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-room, notnull

I'm migrating an app I inherited to Room from SQLOpenHelper and I have a problem with matching one of my tables.

I have a script

```
CREATE TABLE user_groups (
   _id TEXT PRIMARY KEY,
   is_default INTEGER DEFAULT 0 )
```

My Entity class looks like this

```
@Entity(tableName = "user_groups")
public class UserGroupModel {
   @Primary Key
   @NonNull
   @ColumInfo(name = "_id")
   private String rowId;

   @ColumnInfo(name = "is_default")
   private int isDefault;

   ..... constructor / getters .... 
}
```

When I go to make the build with the new database version I get a migration error

> IllegalStateException: Migration didn't properly handle user_groups

The only mismatch I see in the stack trace is Room forces primitive types to be NOT NULL and my old script doesnt.

Expected:

> {name='is_default', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0}

Found:

> {name='is_default', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0}

Room is expecting notNull to be true but since the script didnt specify this its failing. Is there a way around this? Or am I going to have to update all my existing tables with an SQL script to change those INTEGER columns to be NOT NULL and then migrate. That would be a lot of work and really suck!

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: Yes, I ended up doing exactly what I said I didnt want to do in the post.
On migration, I renamed the original tables to temp_table_name. I then recreated the table but put the specific non null qualifiers in the creation script. I then copied all the data from the temp table to the new table.

Comment: Can you please provide the correct code or smth. I am facing similar problem

Answer (score -1):

You can write it in Kotlin:

```
@Entity(tableName = "user_groups")
data class UserGroupModel (
@Primary Key
@ColumInfo(name = "_id")
var rowId: String,
@ColumnInfo(name = "is_default")
var isDefault: Int?)
```